# jQuery if / else if, next / back buttons. Element animations

Tags: jquery, animation, button, jquery-selectors

**Guys, I am a beginner at jQuery.
I am creating a LEGO instruction with jQuery.
What I am trying to do is,
I wanna make 'next' and 'back' buttons, 
and, when I click 'next'
Piece1 is coming down from the top. Then, if I click the 'next' button again, Piece2 is coming down. 
But, If I click 'back' button after Piece1 came down, It should show Piece1 again.

So If I click 'next' in a row, the screen shows 
Piece1 -> piece2 -> piece3 -> piece4 ..
if I click 'next' twice and click 'back once,
piece1 -> piece2 -> piece1 ...
This is what I did and it is working but it does not include the 'back' function.**

How could I add the 'back' function so that the user can go back and forth ? 
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you. 
this is the link

### [go to see what I did here](http://jayleejunha.com/Tom_parking_lot_asmt1/lego_web/jquery_selector.html)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.next').click(function(){
        $('#legs').animate({top: '250px'});
        $('.next').click(function(){
            $('#body1').animate({top: '248px'});
            $('.next').click(function(){
               $('#cape1, #cape2').animate({top: '248px'}); 
               $('.next').click(function(){
                   $('#head1').animate({top: '248px'});
                   $('.next').click(function(){
                       $('#helmet1').animate({top: '248px'});
                   });
               });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

---

Comment: You need stop animation and then remove style tag to achieve your goal,..

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array of the pieces and use the next / back button to reference that array: Note that I couldn't replicate your images / animations - so I dodgied up a list that gets the elements appended to it - then clicking the buttons adds the correct element based on the counter value.

Note you could do a funky effect of removing the elements on the back click - so clicking "next" will aniumate the element down to the image - clicking "back" could animate the last set element off the character and up out of screen.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var options = ['legs','body1','cape1','cape2','head1','helmet1']
var count=0;

  $('#prev').click(function(){
      if(count > 0){count--;}
      updateList(count);
  })

  $('#next').click(function(){
     count++;
     updateList(count);
  })
  
    $('#reset').click(function(){
     count=0;
     $('#sampleList').html('');
     updateList(count);
  })
  
  function updateList(count){
    $('#sampleList').append('<li>' + options[count]+ '</li>')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click the buttons to add to the list</p>
<button id="prev" type="button">Previous</button>
<button id="next" type="button">Next</button>
<button id="reset" type="button">Reset</button>
<hr/>

<ul id="sampleList">
  <li>legs</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sir. I tried to call 'var options' as a selector in several ways, but could not. How could I do that so the elements in 'var options' can be animated by counting. Thanking in advance. [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** ` $('.back').click(function(){
                    //if(count > 0){count--;}
                    updateList(count);
                       
                        if(count>0){count--;}
                         $(options).eq(count).animate({top: '250px'}); 
                })`

Answer (score 0):

Try the code like following to reverse animation

```
// Reverse animation
$("#" + e.id).stop().animate({ top: top }, {
  complete: function() { $(this).removeAttr('style') }
});
$("#" + e.id).removeAttr("style");
```

jquery

```
var e;
var top;
var cnt = 0;
var next = $('.next'); 
var back = $('.back');
back.addClass( "disable" );
var eleCnt = $('.components').find('img').length;
$(document).ready(function(){
  next.click(function(){
    back.removeClass( "disable" );
    if(eleCnt > cnt){
      cnt += 1; 
      if(cnt==eleCnt-1){
        next.addClass( "disable" );
      }
      e = $('.components').find('img')[cnt];
      if(e){
        top=$("#" + e.id).css('top');
        $("#" + e.id).animate({top: '248px'});
      } else {
        cnt -= 1; 
      }
    }
  });

  back.click(function(){
    if(cnt > 0){
      if(cnt == 1){
        back.addClass( "disable" );
      } else {
        next.removeClass( "disable" );
        back.removeClass( "disable" );
      }
      e = $('.components').find('img')[cnt];
    }
    if(e){
      // Reverse animation
      $("#" + e.id).stop().animate({ top: top }, {
        complete: function() { $(this).removeAttr('style') }
      });
      $("#" + e.id).removeAttr("style"); 
      if(cnt > 0){cnt -= 1;}
    }
  });
});
```

Here is the working code:https://jsfiddle.net/5zhb60m3/3/

I think it should be helps you,.